# Problem with printing a linked C structure

Tags: c, pointers, a-star

(The coordinate conventions in my code might be pretty messy for some---it's really weird. I won't explain it unless someone points out that it might be the problem. I think the problem is my use of a "roving" pointer [see traceback below].)

So I have this structure:

```
typedef struct node astarnode;
struct node{
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    astarnode* father;
};
```

on which I run an A* search for a path on a map:

```
void astar(int m,int n,int sx,int sy,int gx,int gy,char *map[]){
    //Yep. A priority queue. Will post code if this happens to be the problem.
PQueue* nodequeue = (PQueue *) malloc(sizeof(PQueue));
initPQueue(nodequeue);
//Just some global variables
rowlimit = m;
collimit = n;
startx = sx;
starty = sy;
goalx = gx;
goaly = gy;
environment = map;

int row = sx;
int col = sy;
astarnode* thisnode = (astarnode *) malloc(sizeof(astarnode));
thisnode->xpos = col;
thisnode->ypos = row;
//The root of the tree is the node with itself as father.
thisnode->father = thisnode;

while(row != gy || col != gx){
    printf("currently in (%d, %d)\n", row, col);
    printAStarNode(thisnode);
    printf("\n");
    //Tedious move functions---see template below
    //putToQueue won't enqueue astarnodes whose fathers are null---see move functions
    astarnode* upleft = moveUpLeft(col, row, thisnode);
    putToQueue(nodequeue, upleft);
    astarnode* up = moveUp(col, row, thisnode);
    putToQueue(nodequeue, up);
    astarnode* upright = moveUpRight(col, row, thisnode);
    putToQueue(nodequeue, upright);
    astarnode* left = moveLeft(col, row, thisnode);
    putToQueue(nodequeue, left);
    astarnode* right = moveRight(col, row, thisnode);
    putToQueue(nodequeue, right);
    astarnode* downleft = moveDownLeft(col, row, thisnode);
    putToQueue(nodequeue, downleft);
    astarnode* down = moveDown(col, row, thisnode);
    putToQueue(nodequeue, down);
    astarnode* downright = moveDownRight(col, row, thisnode);
    putToQueue(nodequeue, downright);
    //And enqueue
    free(thisnode);
    thisnode = (astarnode *) malloc(sizeof(astarnode));
    thisnode = dequeue(nodequeue, thisnode);
    row = thisnode->ypos;
    col = thisnode->xpos;
}
traceback(thisnode);
}
```

My traceback function is

```
void traceback(astarnode* asn){
astarnode* rover = asn;

while(rover->xpos != startx || rover->ypos != starty){
    printAStarNode(rover);
    printf("\n");
    rover = rover->father;
}
}
```

I print astarnode as:

```
void printAStarNode(astarnode *asn){
int address = (int) asn->father;
int myaddress = (int) asn;
printf("%d : (%d, %d, %d)", myaddress, asn->ypos, asn->xpos, address);
}
```

A template of my move functions:

```
astarnode* moveDown(int x, int y, astarnode* pred){
astarnode* downnode = (astarnode *) malloc(sizeof(astarnode));
//Do necessary translations and then reflect to struct
y += 1;
downnode->xpos = x;
downnode->ypos = y;

if(y > rowlimit){ //This move is infeasible.
    downnode->father = NULL;
} else{
    downnode->father = pred;
}

return downnode;
}
```

For which I get the following trace:

```
currently in (0, 0)
149012584 : (0, 0, 149012584)
currently in (1, 1)
149012712 : (1, 1, 149012584)
currently in (2, 2)
149012888 : (2, 2, 149012712)
currently in (3, 3)
149013080 : (3, 3, 149012888)
currently in (3, 4)
149013240 : (3, 4, 149013080)
currently in (4, 5)
149013512 : (4, 5, 149013240)
currently in (5, 6)
149013720 : (5, 6, 149013512)
currently in (6, 6)
149013880 : (6, 6, 149013720)
currently in (6, 7)
149013912 : (6, 7, 149013720)
currently in (7, 8)
149014392 : (7, 8, 149013912)
currently in (8, 8)
149014616 : (8, 8, 149014392)
<Traceback actually starts here>
149014872 : (9, 9, 149014616)
149014616 : (8, 0, 149014392)
149014392 : (7, 0, 149013912)
149013912 : (6, 0, 149013720)
149013720 : (5, 0, 149013512)
149013512 : (4, 0, 149013240)
149013240 : (3, 0, 149013080)
149013080 : (3, 0, 149012888)
149012888 : (2, 0, 149012712)
149012712 : (1, 0, 149012584)
```

The addresses seem correct but why did the xpos' all become 0? Anything I missed?

Comment: Add `rover->father == rover` handling to your rover function conditions unless you are totally, positively sure you will never ever search nonexistent node. If you marked the end with NULL, it would at least crash, but this way it will hang indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your traceback routine prints out nodes that you have already freed. (The free() right after the comment about enqueueing.)

Comment: My bad. Indeed, that is the culprit. I removed the the call to `free()`and the line after it and everything is fine again. Thanks :D